# Loading Static HTML to Webview

Tags: android, html, xhtml, webview

I'm trying to load a static HTML Page into a webview.

When I change its contents to a simple html page it works. 
So I believe something wrong with this html file, however the file is viewed correctly on Mozilla and Chrome. so my questions are

- What common html errors that android webview doesn't pass.
- If something is wrong with the html file then what is it.

The html file
http://snipt.org/vagL9

Screenshot

[image: Emulator Screenshot]

Comment: can you post the code you used to load the html into the WebView?

Comment: I've already included it in the question
The html file http://snipt.org/vagL9

Comment: that is the html code. I am talking about the java code that loads your html file into your WebView.

Comment: Thank you I've found the error, I load the file contents into a String and then modify it's dom. then load the string back. however it didn't work because it contains a '%' character. i think it doesn't escape its conents!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a SDK Bug
The loadData(String, ..., ...) method converts the content of the strings into a uri, and such that my code contains characters that needs to be encoded like % it truncated the code causing errors.
so the solution as found here was to convert those characters to unicode as this code

```
public final static void webViewLoadData(WebView web, String html) {
  StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(html.length());
  for (char c : html.toCharArray()) {
    switch (c) {
      case '#':  buf.append("%23"); break;
      case '%':  buf.append("%25"); break;
      case '\'': buf.append("%27"); break;
      case '?':  buf.append("%3f"); break;                
      default:
        buf.append(c); break;
      }
  }
  web.loadData(buf.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've placed provided html file to assets folder with name `snipt.html`. And this code displays it correctly.

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/snipt.html");
```

Comment: I did that and it didn't work.
I don't load the file directly i load the complete file as a dom and modify its element then get the html back.
however when i removed the '%' character from the file it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

Solved this by applying the code below

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(location);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
String data = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(data.getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

This will fix all issues in webview rendering from android 1.5+

Will definitely work for you!